# (My)SQL how to truncate/split a value to be used elsewhere

Tags: sql, parsing, split

I'm not 100% sure what key words I would be using for this to search, so if there are links please post.

I'm not very experienced with SQL, so am not sure what 'tools' are in the toolbox for this..

but basically I want to query one table (Table A)...  get a value from the column in each row
(example value(s): 2015013 or 2015164 or even 2015009)

truncate/split that value removing the 2015 pre-text... and get the value at the end.

1.) I'm not sure what tools I should be looking into for this?
2.) I'm not sure how to handle the (possible) leading zero or 2?

here is my (feeble) attempt..minus the SQL parsing..

(hope I'm on the right path?)

```
SELECT q1.number 
  FROM TableA q1 
  LEFT JOIN TableB s1 
    ON s1.id=q1.number
 WHERE survey = '2015New';
```

so to recap.. I want to query Table A (q1).. parse that value by trimming off the 2015 in front.. as well as any padding/leading zeros.. then use that to query/grab values in TableB (s1) by the newly parsed 'id'.

Hope that makes sense.

thanks.

update:

I have also tried these without much luck.. the second executes but only seems to return one column ..then an error at the bottom:

```
SELECT q1.number, s1.id, s1.keyword_1, s1.keyword_2
FROM TableA q1
    LEFT JOIN TableB s1 ON s1.id=CAST(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SUBSTR(q1.survey, 5)) AS UNSIGNED)
WHERE survey = '2015New';



SELECT q1.number, s1.id, s1.keyword_1, s1.keyword_2
FROM TableA  q1
    LEFT JOIN TableB s1 ON s1.id=TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM CAST(SUBSTR(q1.survey, 5) AS UNSIGNED));
WHERE survey = '2015New';
```

Comment: Are you referring to the leading zeros that result when you remove the '2015'?  What do you want to happen with them?  Here's a list of string functions available: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html
Also, `WHERE` needs to be moved below your `JOIN`.

Comment: Hi-- I was updating post when you replied. :)  Yes I 'am' refering to the any (possible) leading zeros after stripping off the 2015 in front..  the end result will be as the ID to query the s1 table (TableB)... so if the id is sa: 19... I cant have the 019 left after stripping out the 2015 in front.   Thanks for the link I'll look at it now.

Comment: Is it always the first 4 digits you want to remove?

Comment: actually the engine is important, please confirm mysql

Comment: Sorry I wasnt sure if there would be a difference here.. I believe it just SQL in this case..

Comment: Just `SQL` isn't really an option.  SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle are big ones, many others, but the available functions can vary depending on which you are using.

Comment: Are the numbers the same magnitude. If you drop the leading zeros are the 2015 numbers 2015001 through 2015999 ?

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming the survey field is the one you want to trim
- Assuming you want to skip always the 4 first chars

  ```
  SELECT fields
  FROM TableA q1 
      LEFT JOIN TableB s1 ON s1.id=CAST(SUBSTR(q1.survey, 5) AS UNSIGNED)
  WHERE survey = '2015New';
  ```

But this is horrible, you should think of redesigning your model... The number should be stored as a column all by itself, indexed, and used to join with other tables.

Comment: its an already established table.. with other (older) records in it as well.. and that is the only way I can make the 'relation' between the two tables... is trying to split the 'ID' from the 2015xxx end...and use that to target/query the values I need in table B (s1)..

Can I ask why you have 5 in the substr function? wouldnt that leave me with 2 characters?  also.. how does this handle the (possible) leading 0's?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the query.. I believe the leading 0's might be the last hurdle? I tried this query:



   `SELECT q1.number, s1.id, s1.keyword_1, s1.keyword_2
    FROM TableA q1
            LEFT JOIN TableB s1 ON s1.id=CAST(SUBSTR(q1.survey, 5) AS UNSIGNED)
    WHERE survey = '2015New';`

Comment: hmm.. upon more thought, this might be working. it might not pull/match 'ids' that have leading 0's..but it also didnt pull/match on ones that DO not have any leading 0's..?

Comment: updated original post with my latest query attempts...  (no accepted answer yet)

Comment: the CAST as UNSIGNED will remove leading 0